# Make a call over Avaya PBX WebClient from browser

Tags: webclient, pbx, avaya

We need to integrate our WebApp with Avaya PBX.
Until now we used 3cx PBX and there is it very simple. We can launch the webclient passing the calling number in this way:

> https://blalbait:5001/webclient/#/call?phone=3333342324

We have a webclient in Avaya too, but we are not able to check if we can to somehting like this.

Is this possible in a way?

Answer (score 0):

You can dial like that using integration with Onex-Agent

from browser: uses port 60000 (check on HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Avaya\Avaya one-X Agent\Settings\APIPort)

http://127.0.0.1:60000/onexagent/api/registerclient?name=test

Get the ClientId and add below:
b8704afa-d226-4c38-86c5-17812f6c266d

Make a call
http://127.0.0.1:60000/onexagent/api/voice/makecall?clientid=b8704afa-d226-4c38-86c5-17812f6c266d&number=numbertodialhere

Unregister clientid:
http://127.0.0.1:60000/onexagent/api/unregisterclient?clientid=b8704afa-d226-4c38-86c5-17812f6c266d